# Android ImageView can not locate resource where bitmap can

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, imageview, android-bitmap

xamarin.forms has [a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen#creating-a-drawable-for-the-splash-screen) for creating splash screens in android

This code is my result from following the tutorial **and it works**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/monstersplash"
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

But now I also want my image to aspect-fit on the page.

I found a number of posts suggesting the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/splashlinearlayout"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/monstersplash"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" ></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But this code results in a ResourcesNotFoundException: *android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.companyname.BB.App:drawable/splash_screen with resource ID #0x7f070141*

I tried different configurations with layer-list /linear layout but somehow **the Imageview does not seem to be able to load my monstersplash.png image while the source parameter is the same as with the bitmap.**
Any idea's?

**Full context:**
The above mentioned code lives in drawable/splash_screen.xml
in my styles.xml I have a reference to the drawable like so:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  
  </style>
```

And I created a splashactivity which references the theme

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it works within Bitmap. The issue maybe caused by the IDE or project cache.

1. Delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in your project ,then clean and
   rebuild it.
2. Delete all content in the file Resource.design.cs , then rebuild the project .

If it still doesn't work , you could create a new project and check if the issue still exists .